# How to save this data into Redis by using Jedis library?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am new in redis database and I need a bit help. I need to store lot of values to speciefied key, I'm making a punishment system for Minecraft so I need to store **Player, PlayerUUID, Staff, Reason, Time, Date, Active, Unbanned by, Unban reason, Unban Date**. There are 4 types of punishments(each will have separate table): **Bans, Mutes, Warnings, Blacklists.**

Comment: OK. What have you tried so far and what stopped you?

Comment: Just reasiled that redis is Key-Value database and its very unefficient to store these data into it.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative for storing the data in Redis is to use the [Hash](https://redis.io/topics/data-types) datatype to store your data.  Using code like:

```
try {Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.set("Reason", "Some Reason!");
    ...
    jedis.hmset("player:" + playerUUID + ":", map);
}
```

Assuming the player's UUID is the best primary identifier.  You will likely need to add additional mappings for other lookup keys to the UUID or whatever primary identifier you choose.